# Using "tee" makes the stdout slow

Tags: c, linux, tee

I have a program which does a lot of work. I want to log all the console prints into a file. So i used a tee with my executable.

I implemented a tee which reads from stdin and writes to stdout and a file.

**exec run.sh | tee loglink**

But what i could see is, time to get the login for my program, which used to be 3 mins now is taking 6 mins.

What is the reason for this delay? I commented file operation part of my tee, still seeing the same delay. Is it the pipeline that is causing this issue?

Adding code,

```
char ch;
fd = open(file_name, O_WRONLY | O_APPEND, 0664);
while(read(STDIN_FILENO, &ch, 1) > 0)
{
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, &ch, 1); //write to console
    fflush(stdout);
    write(fd, &ch, 1); //write to the file
}
```

Comment: Very hard to say without code. Are you reading and writing byte by byte or in bigger blocks?

Comment: Doing it char by char, have added the code @Sami Kuhmonen

Comment: Also, `tee` can (and mostly do) mean the command of the shell [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)), the title of the question is confusing

Comment: You should read and write in chunks. You should be prepared to handle `read` reading less than a full chunk.

Comment: "Doing it char by char". That's your problem right here.

Comment: let me give a try with chunks

Comment: I dont see any difference even if i read block by block... changed char ch; to char ch[100];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
read(STDIN_FILENO, &ch, 1)
```

You only read 1 byte per read call. it is very very slow, please increase the buffer, and read as more as you can per read call

Comment: I dont see any difference even if i read block by block... changed char ch; to char ch[100];